# Comparison an array in java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have problem regarding how to compare string in an array..
in my list have jack,john,nami@domain,nami

```
function **alreadyInList**(list, toBeAdded) {
    // return true or false
    var delims = "(,)";
    var tokens = list.split(delims);

    for ( var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){

        if (tokens[i] === toBeAdded  ){ 
            return true;    
        }
        else 
            return false;

        }
}

function addListTo(selectbox, textbox) {
    var values = new Array();
    var c = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < selectbox.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectbox.options[i].selected) {
            if (!**alreadyInList**(textbox.value,selectbox.options[i].value)) {
                values[c++] = selectbox.options[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
    if (values.length == 0) return;

    var v = values[0];
    for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            v += ',' + values[i];
    }
    if (textbox.value.length>0) {
        if (textbox.value=='Any') {
            textbox.value = v;
        } else {
            textbox.value += ',';
            textbox.value += v;
    }

    } else {
        textbox.value += v;
    }
}
```

when i put my condition and i want to add the string into textbox it only work for the first string lets say i put nami as my string then when i want to put nami again it cannot so it works..but after "," i put name@domain .i can put back nami..means i dont want to repetitive string inside my textbox.can someone help me.sorry im still new in this programming..sorry for my english

Comment: `Java != JavaScript`. [tag:java] tag removed.

Comment: Can you put up some HTML or a small example at http://jsfiddle.net/ ? Also I believe you want `split(",")` which then breaks up tokens into an array by ",". So `var delims` should be `var delims = ",";`

Comment: The `.split()` API does not work the way you think it does. The string argument is not interpreted as a list of delimiters; it **is** the delimiter, in its entirety.

Comment: @Putra perhaps you can explain me in Malay language since I don't understand your statement above -_-

Comment: what u mean by .split()API doenst work?? @Pointy

Comment: @WASasquatch yup i want to split it by "," .i dunt know how to put it in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Putra if you want to split by `","` then it should be `var delims = ",";` instead of `var delims = "(,)";`

Comment: @ImmerAllein thanks..aku ada satu textbox and list.aku try pakai RegExp so tak boleh..aku buat satu javascript function untuk split kan string dari list..now problem nya aku boleh add 1 nama example nami..and lepas tu tak boleh letak nami sebab split tu..tp selepas aku letak nami@domain then nami boleh letak balik..result yg aku nak  mcm nami,nami@domain,john not nami,nami@domain,nami@domain.

Comment: @Putra I revised your function in a answer below. Take a look.

Comment: @WASasquatch i already revise your code..got a few question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a revised version of your function to check if a name appears twice in any string in the array

```
function alreadyInList(list, toBeAdded) {

    // return true or false
    var delims = ",",
        tokens = list.split(delims),
        found = false;

    var end = tokens.forEach(function (value) {
        if (value.indexOf(toBeAdded) !== -1 && found == false) {
            found = true;
            alert('It\'s been found!');
            // Do something
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    if (found != true) {
        alert('Not in the list');
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

alreadyInList('marry,joe,gerry', 'marry');
```

## [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/AEqM6/)

Additionally if its just one occurance in the list you need something simple without a function.

```
var str = "marry,joe,gerry",
   key =  "marry";

if ( str.indexOf(key) !== -1 )  {
    // Its found! Do something
}
```

Comment: I made a booboo, be sure to checked updated version in answer.

Comment: i already revise your code..it inform me when a repetitive string inside the text box..now what i want is when it detect have repetitive string it will not add the same string inside the textbox @WASasquatch

Comment: @Putra If your function is ran where it says "do something" it will only run when its found that key in one of the list elements. It runs on each occurance. Do you mean only running once on the first occurance?

Comment: yup..it will only run once means i only can add those string once..inside those textbox cannot have repetitive string..means that after i have been found it will not add the same string to textbox

Comment: @Putra If you wrap thr code inside the `forEach` with a condition `if ( found == false ) { /* the code insode forEach */ }` it should only do anything if its not found. Sorry on my phone can't write much or get on jsfiddle. Ill be home soon.

Comment: kay noted..i will try to change a little bit the code..

Comment: i really don't understand why still got same string in the textbox..

Comment: @Putra Added nrw method on my phone to answer take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As Sasquatch pointed out above, the issue is the delimiter you are using for split.  You want to split by a single comma ',' -- not by the three characters '(,)'.

The way your code is written, tokens only ever has a single value because the split delimiter is wrong.  It is matching the entire string variable list to your toBeAdded string and returning false.